# Hamachi gateway PC responds when pinging remote PCs from internal network

Tags: domain-name-system, ping, internal-dns, hamachi

We are using Hamachi to link 2 remote sites together via a gateway VPN network.

This *generally* works fine.

At our main office, our SBS 2003 server acts as the DHCP server. The Hamachi gateway client on an XP computer at this site allows remote computers to get an IP address from the SBS 2003 server's DHCP when using VPN (for their Hamachi virtual network adapter).

The only problem is that if anyone in the main office attempts to ping the remote PC by hostname, it resolves to the IP of the Hamachi gateway PC (192.168.1.**2**) instead of the remote computer's IP (192.168.1.**191**).

If we instead ping 192.168.1.191 directly, then there is a response from that IP- so basic connectivity over the VPN link is fine. I'm fairly sure this is a DNS issue, but have no idea how to resolve it.

In DHCP on the server, the remote PC is statically-assigned 192.168.1.191 as a reservation.

There is also an A record in the forward lookup zone, and a PTR record in the reverse lookup zone for the remote computer on the server- so I am surprised we are having DNS problems.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing the Hamachi gateway to respond to ping requests meant for remote PCs? (i.e. why is DNS resolving the wrong IP for the remote PC's hostname?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved itself- it seems it just took a while (30 minutes or so) for the new DNS entries to become active.

Pinging remote hosts now results in the correct IP responding.

Could anyone shed some light on how long it usually takes for new A records in DNS to start working so I know what to expect next time?

Comment: That depends entirely on the TTL values you had set for your DNS records.

Comment: It says 1 hour on that particular A record. So does that mean it takes exactly 1 hour from its creation until it goes into effect?

Comment: I just saw this response today. DNS entries are _cached_ by resolvers; DNS is not "propagated". The TTL is how long the record is supposed to be cached.